# Assign incremental value to multiple entries with same identifier

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this kind of situation, whereby the same value (Item) can have multiple dates assigned

```html
Item1   01/01/2018
Item1   01/03/2018
Item1   01/05/2018
Item2   01/01/2018
Item2   01/03/2018
Item3   01/03/2018
```

Is there a way to assign a number to each date value for the same Item, so that the output would be an incremental list of number (starting at 1 for each different Item and counting)?

```html
Item1   01/01/2018   1
Item1   01/03/2018   2
Item1   01/05/2018   3
Item2   01/01/2018   1
Item2   01/03/2018   2
Item3   01/03/2018   1
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT item, dt, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY item ORDER BY PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', dt)) value
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using sample data you provided as

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Item1' item, '01/01/2018' dt UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Item1', '01/03/2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Item1', '01/05/2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Item2', '01/01/2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Item2', '01/03/2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Item3', '01/03/2018' 
)
SELECT item, dt, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY item ORDER BY PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', dt)) value
FROM `project.dataset.table`
ORDER BY item, dt
```

with result

```
Row item    dt          value    
1   Item1   01/01/2018  1    
2   Item1   01/03/2018  2    
3   Item1   01/05/2018  3    
4   Item2   01/01/2018  1    
5   Item2   01/03/2018  2    
6   Item3   01/03/2018  1
```

Comment: Hi Mikhail, thanks for the quick answer, it's exactly what I needed! Really appreciated the help!